# reading sql data using angular js

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs

am trying to read data from an sql table using Angular,can't seem to find my problem cause my debugger isn't recognizing it,Attached is the html and php file am using,any here will be greatly appreciated.
here is the code:

**HTML+JS**

```
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="customersController" class="container">

<p><input type="text" ng-model="name" class="form-control"></p>



<table  class="table table-bordered">

<tr>
<th>Full Name</th>
<th>Email Address</th>
<th>Password</th>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="x in names | filter:name | orderBy:'Fullname'">
<td><a href="#">{{ x.Fullname }}</a></td>
<td>{{ x.Email }}</td>
<td>{{ x.Password }}</td>
 </tr>
</table>
</div>





    <script src="js/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script>
  function customersController($scope,$http) {

  var page = "sql.php";
 $http.get(page)
 .success(function(response) {$scope.names = response;});
 }
 </script>

 </body>
```

**sql.php**

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
 header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");

  $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "", "", "") or die(mysqli_error());

$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `user` ORDER BY `id` ASC");

$outp = "[";
while($rs = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
if ($outp != "[") {$outp .= ",";}
$outp .= '{"Full Name":"'  . $rs["fullname"] . '",';
$outp .= '"Email":"'   . $rs["emailAddress"]        . '",';
$outp .= '"Password":"'. $rs["user_pass"]     . '"}';
}
$outp .="]";

$conn->close();

echo($outp);
?>
```

Comment: Add a failure handler to $http call to see what went wrong. Depending on where you place the HTML and the php file, the path you use for $http request may have problems. First ensure path is correct and work towards a solution from there. Another way is - use a debugger to see the request and the response details in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending a content-type header of text/html, and then constructing your own json string.  Kill that header, and do as follows:

```
$outp = array();
while( $rs = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC) ) $outp[] = $rs;
$conn->close();
echo json_encode($outp);
exit();
```

Comment: i tried the above but same result,firebug seems to give me this error when debugging: